# Empty RichTextBox start with Bold

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a problem. When i start working with RichTextBox (it is empty) I cannot change format to Bold.
I try to type (CTRL+B) but after I typed something the text is normal (not bold).

The text only changes format when I type something before. This happens again when I SelectAll and Clear all Content.

Is it bug in RichTextBox, or I can do something with it.

Best Regards,
_alexiej

Comment: not sure what version of .NET you are using but in .NET 4, I've tried what you described on an empty RichTextBox, it works expectedly. Right after pressing `CTRL+B` and typing some text the  whole text is applied with Bold font normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's normal, usually you decide what is bold or not after you've written the text. If you want this button to act like ( on off ) you have to change it yourself.